# Restrict access to assets from asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, restriction

Is there some way, any way to limit access to the rails asset pipeline for users browsing your app?

I want to limit access to certain CSS only when a user is logged in, rails should block access to it otherwise.

Could not find anything relating this 
Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally i will compile the assets i dont want public separately in my production.rb file

example

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(locked.css )
```

then in my application layout i will add a yield to the head tag

example

```
<%= yield(:head)%>
```

then i can now perform my check to know if there is a current_user or not

example

```
<% if current_user %>
  <%= provide(:head) do %>
     <% stylesheet_link_tag "locked" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This might be kind of lame but it gets the job done.

Comment: Yes but I want to disable /assets/whatever.css also, so they should not be able to get the contents at all. Guess this requires serving the assets true a controller making everything extreme complicated

Comment: grant yours as correct answer, not a full solution to my problem but its correct.